# Browse database with a loop

Tags: database, nginx, proxy, proxypass

I have a database containing 3 parameters: name, http_host and http_port

```
stardb=# select name, http_host, http_port from data ;
 name  |   http_host   | http_port 
-------+---------------+-----------
 user2 | 127.0.0.1     | 80
 user1 | 192.x.x.x.    | 80
```

I would like to create a loop in my nginx server, so that each name it makes a proxy_pass http://$http_host:$http_port concerned.

Here's what I did:

```
location /getIp {
    default_type 'text/plain';
    rds_json          on;

    set $name '';

    postgres_pass       database;
    postgres_query      "SELECT http_host FROM data WHERE name = \'$name\'";
    postgres_output     rds;
    }

    location /getPort {
        default_type 'text/plain';
        rds_json          on;

        set $name '';

        postgres_pass       database;
        postgres_query      "SELECT http_port FROM data WHERE name = \'$name\'";
        postgres_output     rds;
    }

    location /$name {
        ip = ngx.location.capture("/getIp", {
            method = ngx.HTTP_GET
        })
        port = ngx.location.capture("/getPort", {
            method = ngx.HTTP_GET
        })

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://$ip:$port;
    }
```

But I do not see how to make a loop to browse the database.